# Dynamically modify values in data.table in R but getting only single constant value returned

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to modify some values in data.tables in R.
I have come up with a command which I thought would do the job, but instead it puts the same value in every row, while it should be dependent on the information in that row.
Here is my command:

```
TableA[,ColA := TableB[ColBD == unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(ColC," +"))[1], "-"))[1] 
                     & ColBC == unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(ColC," +"))[1], "-"))[2] 
                     & ColBB == unlist(strsplit(unlist(strsplit(ColC," +"))[1], "-"))[3]
                      ,ColBA]]
```

So I want ColA from TableA to take the value of ColBA from TableB that corresponds to the date from ColC in TableA.
This is an example from TableA

```
   ColA ColB                ColC
 1: 600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
 2: 600   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
 3: 600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
 4: 600   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
 5: 600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
 6: 600   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
 7: 600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
 8: 600   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
 9: 600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
10: 600   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
```

This is the relevant part from TableB:

```
   ColBA ColBB ColBC ColBD
1:   600    14    12  2012
2:   601    15    12  2012
```

This is what the resulting TableA should look like

```
   ColA ColB                ColC
 1: 600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
 2: 601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
 3: 600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
 4: 601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
 5: 600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
 6: 601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
 7: 600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
 8: 601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
 9: 600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
10: 601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
```

I hope this is clear enough!

---

So using the information from @DavidArenburg my code would be more efficient by using the `as.Date()` and `ISOdate` functions, which I didn't know I could use on this data. My command would become like this:

```
TableA[,ColA := TableB[as.Date(ColC) == as.Date(ISOdate(ColBD,ColBC,ColBB)), ColBA]]
```

This works (for this testset, but not for a larger sample of my data), but this gives me the warning:

```
Warning message:
In `==.default`(as.Date(ColC), as.Date(ISOdate(ColBD, ColBC,  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: Your modified code doesn't work. It gives wrong results. What `data.table` version you have?

Comment: R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)  
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)  
data.table_1.9.4

Comment: How does `TableA$ColA` looks like after you run your code? I see that only the first two rows are populated and everything else is `NA`s

Comment: That does not happen here. What version do you have?
I don't get NA's but testing it on a bigger dataset revealed it just repeats the first two results forever regardless of changes to the ColC.. I'll just go for the merge version xD

Comment: The same as you have. You've got correct results for the data set you provided in the question?

Comment: I am beginning to realize that I am bringing too much `PyThink` into `R`...
In other instances I am also trying to add values to columns in `data.table`s and I thought I could do that in this way, but now I am starting to believe that the only way is to calculate the values first in one table and merge it into another table keyed by some column..
My logic is that I try to reference certain rows in `tableA` by comparing colums from `tableA` and `tableB` and then take the other column values and work them into some value to put in a new or existing column in `tableA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it very inefficiently. This is not how you should work with `data.table`.

Here's one efficient way to solve this (there are probably more efficient ways)

```
setkey(TableB[, indx := as.Date(ISOdate(ColBD, ColBC, ColBB))], indx)
setkey(TableA[, indx := as.Date(ColC)], indx)
TableA[TableB, ColA := ColBA][, indx := NULL][]
#     ColA ColB                ColC
#  1:  600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
#  2:  600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
#  3:  600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
#  4:  600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
#  5:  600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
#  6:  601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
#  7:  601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
#  8:  601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
#  9:  601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
# 10:  601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
```

Here we are creating an `index` column in each data set (only once and assigning it by reference, instead of calling it multiple times) which will be used for merging while assigning the correct values in `ColBA` to `ColA`

---

If you insist on retaining you original rows order, you can slightly modify the code as following

```
setkey(TableB[, indx := as.Date(ISOdate(ColBD, ColBC, ColBB))], indx)
setkey(TableA[, `:=`(indx = as.Date(ColC), order = .I)], indx)
setorder(TableA[TableB, ColA := ColBA], order)[, `:=`(indx = NULL, order = NULL)][]
#     ColA ColB                ColC
#  1:  600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
#  2:  601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
#  3:  600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
#  4:  601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
#  5:  600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
#  6:  601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
#  7:  600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
#  8:  601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
#  9:  600   93 2012-12-14 23:45:00
# 10:  601   93 2012-12-15 23:45:00
```

Comment: Thank you, this works.
But besides maybe being inefficient, what is wrong with my code?
It might be good to know that my TableA has over 6M rows, so efficiency is key :) I'd just like some more information on why, because data.table is not very intuitive for me and I thought my solution in one line was very neat.

Comment: Usually running multiple `unlist` `strsplit` combinations multiple times won't be efficient (and it has nothing to do with `data.table`. Also `data.table` `merge` abilities are very efficient and thus you should use them (especially on `key`ed data sets). Moreover, modifying columns by reference (using `:=`) is another unique option that you can only do with `data.table`. Joining everything up equals efficiency. Thus, as mentioned in the answer, there are probably even more efficient ways of doing this. Will wait for @Arun to hear his opinion

Comment: But you don't see why my code is broken? :(
It is using :=

Comment: Ok, I still don't know why my first line of code does not work, while the new code I edited into my question does. It seems to do the same thing but more efficient.
I will test both our solutions on my big data set and post runtimes

Comment: Your modified code gives wrong results. Your biggest problem is that you are trying to merge unkeyed data sets using the `[]` merge which is impossible. You need to create an index column and key the data sets by it

Comment: I don't think it does, at least it didn't on the test Table.
Also, I don't think what I am doing actually counts as a merge.
It's more of a instant way to change the values in a complete row of the data.table. i.e. it assigns values into my original data.table rather than merging two data.tables.
But if I am misunderstanding, please explain a little more elaborately.